# No target method found in functional interface

Tags: java, functional-interface

I am trying to learn more about the Java 8 `FunctionalInterface` annotation. I wrote the following code as an experiment, but it does not compile:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface HasToString {

    String toString();
}
```

> No target method found

Interestingly, this *does* compile:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface HasToString {

    String notToString();
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: You're overriding the toString() method of Object. So it's not an abstract method, but a concrete one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is stated in the [JLS 9.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8)

> A functional interface is an interface that has just one abstract method **(aside from the methods of Object)**, and thus represents a single function contract. This "single" method may take the form of multiple abstract methods with override-equivalent signatures inherited from superinterfaces; in this case, the inherited methods logically represent a single method.

As `toString` is a "*public instance method of the class Object*", your interface doesn't qualify to be a functional interface.

Comment: Exactly, everything besides instance methods of Object